# Ready to use ubuntu based virtual machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine

Are there any pre-installed virtual machine-based ununtu linux boxes that I can directly download and use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[virtualboxes.org](http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/)

I've used them in a pinch and never had aproblem. They are pretty basic but they are a good start. I personally just do an install from an ISO unless I am really in a hurry. It is fast and I know exactly what I am going to get.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, since the machine I will used does not allow me to  run any installation script, including installing virtual box itself. I am not sure whether your approach means that I can just download-and -use?

Comment: The image won't do you any good if you don't have vm software running on the box you want to use it on.